# More advanced makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am currently creating (well at least I'm trying) to create a makefile for a software project.

Since I never used make before I quickly ran into problems.

The software project contains of many subfolders and subsubfolders containing source and header files.

Those files should be collected recursivly and after that beeing build and linked using cross arm toolchain.

The current makefile looks as following:

```
    RM := rm -rf

# Every subdirectory with source files must be described here

DIR := \
    D:/foxmake/

SUBDIRS := \
    src/test                                     \
    src/test/usb_cdc_lolevel                     \
    src/os                                       \
    src/os/FreeRTOS/Source                       \
    src/os/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MemMang      \
    src/os/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F \
    src/os/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS            \
    src/module/uart                              \
    src/module/spi                               \
    src/module/rcc                               \
    src/module/ltc                               \
    src/module/irq                               \
    src/module/io                                \
    src/module/eeprom                            \
    src/module/dma                               \
    src/module/cpu                               \
    src/module/contactor                         \
    src/module/config                            \
    src/module/com                               \
    src/module/can                               \
    src/module/adc                               \
    src/hal/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src             \
    src/general                                  \
    src/general/config                           \
    src/engine/task                              \
    src/engine/sysctrl                           \
    src/engine/sof                               \
    src/engine/soc                               \
    src/engine/isoguard                          \
    src/engine/diag                              \
    src/engine/database                          \
    src/engine/config                            \
    src/application/task                         \
    src/application/config                       \

CFLAGS := \
    -mcpu=cortex-m4           \
    -mthumb -mlittle-endian   \
    -mfloat-abi=softfp        \
    -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16         \
    -O0                       \
    -fmessage-length=0        \
    -fsigned-char             \
    -ffunction-sections       \
    -fdata-sections           \
    -ffreestanding            \
    -fno-move-loop-invariants \
    -Wall                     \
    -g3                       \
    -std=gnu11                \
    -DSTM32F429xx             \
    -DDEBUG                   \
    -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT         \
    -DTRACE                   \
    -DOS_USE_TRACE_ITM        \
    -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER          \
    -DHSE_VALUE=8000000

INCDIRS := \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/application"                              \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/application/config"                       \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/application/task"                         \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/adc"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/can"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/com"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/config"                            \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/contactor"                         \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/cpuload"                           \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/io"                                \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/ltc"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/spi"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/uart"                              \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/engine/config"                            \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/engine/database"                          \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/engine/diag"                              \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/engine/isoguard"                          \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/engine/soc"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/engine/sof"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/engine/sysctrl"                           \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/engine/task"                              \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/general"                                  \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/general/config"                           \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/general/includes"                         \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/hal/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include"    \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/hal/CMSIS/Include"                        \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/hal/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"             \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/os"                                       \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/os/FreeRTOS"                              \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/os/FreeRTOS/Source"                       \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/os/FreeRTOS/Source/include"               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/os/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS"            \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/os/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F" \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/test"                                     \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/cpu"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/dma"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/irq"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/module/rcc"                               \
    -I"D:/foxmake/src/test/usb_cdc_lolevel"

S_UPPER_SRCS := \
    $(DIR)src/general/config/startup_stm32f429xx.S

S_UPPER_DEPS := \
    ./src/general/config/startup_stm32f429xx.d

rwildcard = $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2) $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d))

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
C_SRCS := \
    $(call rwildcard, , *.c)
#$(info C_SRCS='$(C_SRCS)')
OBJDIR := objdir

OBJS := \
    $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(C_SRCS))

#$(error OBJS='$(OBJS)')
# comment the above line once OBJS is ok.

C_DEPS := \
    $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(C_SRCS))
#$(info C_DEPS='$(C_DEPS)')

%.o: %.c ,$(C_SRCS)
    echo 'Building file: $<'
    echo 'Invoking: Cross ARM C Compiler'
    arm-none-eabi-gcc $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$@" -c -o "$@" "$<"
    echo 'Finished building: $<'
    echo ' '

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(ASM_DEPS)),)
-include $(ASM_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(S_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(S_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
endif

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables
SECONDARY_FLASH := \
    foxbms.hex \

SECONDARY_LIST := \
    foxbms.lst \

SECONDARY_SIZE := \
    foxbms.siz \

# All Target
all: foxbms.elf secondary-outputs

# Tool invocations
foxbms.elf: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross ARM C++ Linker'
    arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -g3 -T "D:/foxmake/src/STM32F429ZIT6_FLASH.ld" -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"foxbms.map" --specs=nano.specs -o "foxbms.elf" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory post-build

foxbms.hex: foxbms.elf
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Create Flash Image'
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "foxbms.elf" "foxbms.hex"
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

foxbms.lst: foxbms.elf
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Create Listing'
    arm-none-eabi-objdump --source --all-headers --demangle --line-numbers --wide "foxbms.elf" > "foxbms.lst"
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

foxbms.siz: foxbms.elf
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size'
    arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley $(OBJS) "foxbms.elf"
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) \
        $(CC_DEPS)         \
        $(C++_DEPS)        \
        $(OBJS)            \
        $(C_UPPER_DEPS)    \
        $(CXX_DEPS)        \
        $(SECONDARY_FLASH) \
        $(SECONDARY_LIST)  \
        $(SECONDARY_SIZE)  \
        $(ASM_DEPS)        \
        $(S_UPPER_DEPS)    \
        $(C_DEPS)          \
        $(CPP_DEPS)        \
        foxbms.elf
    -@echo ' '

post-build:
    -@echo 'Create binary'
    -arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary "foxbms.elf" "foxbms.bin"
    -@echo ' '

secondary-outputs: $(SECONDARY_FLASH) $(SECONDARY_LIST) $(SECONDARY_SIZE)

.PHONY: all clean dependents x
.SECONDARY: post-build
```

using eclipse to execute this makefile gives me this error:

```
make all 
cc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -g3 -std=gnu11 -DSTM32F429xx -DDEBUG -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_ITM -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DHSE_VALUE=8000000   -c -o src/general/nvic.o src/general/nvic.c
<builtin>: recipe for target 'src/general/nvic.o' failed
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -Wall -g3 -std=gnu11 -DSTM32F429xx -DDEBUG -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_ITM -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DHSE_VALUE=8000000 -c -o src/general/nvic.o src/general/nvic.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): System is unable to find the given file.

make: *** [src/general/nvic.o] Error 2
```

Anyone knows why my makefile fails?
What's wrong with the rule "%.o: %.c ,$(C_SRCS)"?

Comment: Where is your Makefile located relative to your source?

Comment: it's top level, paths are as following: D:\foxmake\makefile, D:\foxmake\src\...

Comment: It's not using the rule you have pointed out. It is using an implicit inbuilt rule as shown in the error message (you can also see that because the command is not the one in that rule). Can't be sure, but perhaps the `,$(C_SRCS)` is confusing make. I'm not sure why you want to put `$(C_SRCS)` there as each `.o` should only depend on it's own `.c`. And even  if you want to make a multiple dependency target, you should not use `,` (comma). The make syntax uses a space to seperate multiple dependencies. Not sure if the comma is confusing it.

Comment: The error message for CreateProcess seems to indicate that `cc` is not found. Is the PATH correctly configured for Eclipse ?

Comment: yes you were right, the ,$(C_SRCS) was the problem, without it compiles at least. now i'm just getting linker errors :/

Comment: is there a way to only add the .c files from the listed subdirs ( $(SUBDIRS) ) and not ALL like i'm doing it currently?

Comment: AFAICS your makefile is trying to build just the C files listed in $SUBDIRS. What is `ALL` that you are referring to?

Comment: rwildcard = $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2) $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d))

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
C_SRCS := \
 $(call rwildcard, , *.c) called from the root directory walks ALL folders including subfolders and subsubfolders (and so on). i want it to walk only the folders listed in SUBDIRS..

Comment: how do you mark something as code in a comment? the shortcut crtl + k doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Oh sorry I misread that. Though that was adding only SUBDIR files. But I can't give you the exact commands. It would be too easy to get wrong without thorough debugging. But I have used something like `C_SRCS := $(shell find $(SUBDIR) -name '*.c')`. Obviously you have to do that foreach entry in $SUBDIRS. To mark as comment surround code with backticks (`).

Comment: `C_SRCS := \
 $(foreach d,$(SUBDIRS),$(call rwildcard, , *.c))` seems to work. all linker errors are gone now besides this one:`Invoking: Cross ARM C++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ <FLAGGS> -T "D:/foxmake/src/STM32F429ZIT6_FLASH.ld" -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"foxbms.map" --specs=nano.specs -o "foxbms.elf" src/general/nvic.o src/general/main.o src/general/version.o src/engine............... /FreeRTOS/Source/timers.o  ", ...) failed.
make (e=206): the filename or extension is too long`.

Comment: instead of filename.o he also uses the complete path..i had to shorten the output above to not exceed the post limit

Comment: seems he's adding way too many object files. the IDE generated makefile passes about 6000 cols, where my own file passes over 200 000 seems there are many duplicates in the OBJS variable...